# How can carbon flows be modeled mathematically?

Tags: climate-change, climate-models, co2

In this video Earth's carbon cycle is investigated with a bit of maths.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIOrF0-R33o

It is in German, but the idea behind I can describe easily:

There are reservoirs of carbon:

- Atmosphere A
- Biosphere B
- Upper sea M
- Deep sea T

This is the relevant image:

[image]

The author has taken the image (most likely) from the IPCC report and adjusted the in- and out flows so that all four reservoir contents are in quasi-static equilibrium for simplicity. For the flows from F(X->Y) from X to Y he assumes, that it depends only on the content X, in particular for instance

$$F(A\rightarrow B) = \frac{110}{600}\cdot [A]$$

I'm aware that the model is very crude but nevertheless, what's the idea behind? It would mean, that F(X->Y) depends only on X and not on Y. Take for instance F(A->B) and we double carbon in A, the assumption would imply, that biomass increases also by factor two - otherwise the additional carbon cannot be "absorbed" by B. Same for F(A, M). When CO<sub>2</sub> increases in air, temperature of M would rise too, but then less CO<sub>2</sub> would be taken by the warmer water, so the coefficient of transport would change.

Is there a way to justify the assumption in a first approximation?